# Azure Web App throws "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm having issues getting the response from the server using certificate. It works fine running locally. But when I publish on Azure Web App it throws "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

Following is the code snippet:

```
String Token = "";    
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;    
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

String uri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URI"];
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "GET"; // Get method
request.ContentType = "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8";// content type
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Certificates/certificate.pfx"), "SFhbu1&5"); //The path to the certificate and the passphrase

request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    Token = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (including the specific url it is trying to hit).

Comment: Where do you store yout cert ? Azure webapp can store the cert for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-ssl-cert-load. Let me know if you need more information